# How can I recover laptop programs and data with new hardware?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have an HP pv6000 laptop and the motherboard is bad. How can I move the hard drive to another computer and have a working computer will all the installed programs and data?

Comment: Clone the drive with something like acronis plus which supports restoration to dissimilar hardware but you will need a new Windows license

Answer (score 0):

The first decision you have to make is do you want to keep the hard drive (not the data and programs on the hard drive but the physical hard drive itself)? If you want to keep the physical hard drive than all you may have to do is move it to another computer that has the same interface (probably SATA III). There could be issues with the operating system rejecting different hardware, but the more similar the new hardware is to the old one the more likely you would not have any problems.

The other option is to copy the data from the old hard drive to a new one on a different computer. There are several different approaches to this. You probably want to use an imaging program, such as Acronis True Image or a free alternative (such as one of the one's [listed here](https://superuser.com/questions/197384/acronis-true-image-free-open-source-alternative)).

Technically there is a distinction between cloning and imaging, imaging compresses files where cloning doesn't and copies multiple partitions. [Read here for more details](http://www.whatsabyte.com/P1/Image_or_Clone.html).